# Connecting Azure VPN Site to Site with my Cisco Router (RV350)

Tags: vpn, routing, cisco, azure, site-to-site-vpn

I have a Cisco RV320 Router, and currently we can not upgrade to anything bigger.  I am trying to create a  Site to Site VPN between Azure and my Router.

I do realize that the RV325 is not supported by Microsoft as they have not tested it.  But I have seen where it is possible.

The VPN is not connecting, and I know that I am so close.  How is it that I can’t debug this either on my Router side, nor on the Azure side, to see what is missing?

Below is my router screen shot, please point me in the right direction.  Again, I know that I am very close.

## In Azure

### Network

Network Name: TESNET
Address Space: 10.10.2.0/24
Subnets: 
   - default: 10.10.2.0/26
   - GatewaySubnet: 10.10.2.64/10

### Virtual Network Gateways

Name: HOUVPN:
IP Address: 
VPN Type: Route-based

## On Prem

Router Type: RV325
Address Space: 10.10.1.0/24

By the way, I noticed that someone had the same exact issue but was able to resolve it here: [What are the VPN configuration requirements for site-to-site VPN with Azure?](https://serverfault.com/questions/658236/what-are-the-vpn-configuration-requirements-for-site-to-site-vpn-with-azure/658249#658249).  But I tried this, and it didn't work.  But I assume they were working in the older version of Azure.
I have also tried these settings, but still no luck: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpn-devices

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't confirm this info, but I don't think your router supports IKEv2. That said, you must configure Azure Gateway as Policy-Based instead of Route-Based.

Delete and recreate the gateway as Policy-Based and set TTL of Phase1 to 28800. If you are using ARM, Public IP can be reused.

Comment: You don't need to delete your gateway anymore. Now the choice of policy-based / route-based in done on a per-connection basis and you can mix both on the same gateway pair.